# Can't get class or tag elements in native javascript

Tags: javascript, onload, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to hide some elements after document loaded. I manage to do this with `getElementById` but can't manage to do this while using `getElementsByClassName` or `getElementsByTagName`.

I have read lots questions and answers but coundn't find the solution. [Here is sample fiddle.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/owCma)

javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("b").style.display="none";
  document.getElementsByTagName('p').style.display="none";
  document.getElementsByClassName("a").style.display="none";
}
onload = myFunction;
```

html:

```
<p>Tag Ele Test</p>
<p class="a">Class Test</p>
<p id="b">ID Test</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getElement**s**  ([`byTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName), [`byClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName)) does return a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList), which you need to iterate over. It has no single `style` declaration property.

```
var element = document.getElementById("b");
if (element != null)
    element.style.display = "none";
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++)
    elements[i].style.display = "none";
elements = document.getElementsByClassName("a");
for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++)
    elements[i].style.display = "none";
```

Comment: Saw the nodeList alert earlier, now i get it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `getElementsByTagName()` and `getElementsByClassName()` is that both return a set of elements you need to iterate, whereas `getElementById()` returns a single element.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

**References:**

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: @BarlasApaydin This is **not** a *problem* though ;)

Comment: true in your point of view but it still represents problem for newbies on js (; @Vision

Comment: @BarlasApaydin Yeah, but what I say it is mostly a *peculiarity* of these methods but not their problem.

Comment: lol, downvote for this matter mate? be pro and read the question and u'll see, the is no _"problem"_ word usage. i was just trying to work that function out, and u were being mean. (: anyways, take care.

Comment: @BarlasApaydin Mean? You've taken back my 15 points for **absolutely** correct answer, which I gave first. For some reason you've considered my answer as not correct, I've considered your question as too elementary for being asked -- just read any JS docs and you'll get a solution. Just be pro and give a hint how my answer is worse than another one before reverting the acceptance. My regards.